# MySQL Innodb: What is the difference between running 'mysqlcheck --optimize --all-database' compared to running 'optimize table' in the mysql client?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Without having to script an 'optimize table' query to do all the databases/tables, we would like to run `mysqlcheck --optimize --all-database` instead.

What are the drawbacks of doing this through `mysqlcheck`; both would defragment the tables, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqlcheck just runs a bunch of 'optimize table' SQL statements for you, so functionally they do the same thing.

Note that 'optimize table' for innodb just maps to an 'ALTER TABLE foo engine = innodb' statement.  This rebuilds the entire table.  Depending on the size of your table this may take a very long time, during which the table is locked and unavailable.